# istream manipulators for reading double

Tags: c++, istream, istringstream, manipulators

I need to read numbers like `14.3925125E` from istringstream as part of formatted input. `E` meaning east, not scientific notation.
When I try to use `input >> double >> char` it looks like the stream takes the number as wrong scientific and fails. I tried manipulators `std::fixed` and `std::dec` but it didn't help. Is there something else i can use?

Comment: You could try reading it to a string first, remove the "E"  and then use the C++11 standard library function `stod` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/)  to parse it as a `double`. If you don't have access to C++11, you could use a `stringstream` to achieve this.

Comment: That sounds good, but the whole input looks like this `(50.1003781N, 14.3925125E)` and i also need to verify the format of it, so i was really hoping i could use  the stream

Comment: You'll still be using the stream to read each consecutive "word" (blank-delimited by default). There's probably many ways of doing this, which is why I posted as a comment rather than an answer. My way is just an easy quick fix, do whatever you like with it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulators won't do it, because E is part of how floating point values are represented as text.   For example  `14.25E2` represents the value `1425.00`.

You need to extract substrings and parse them separately.   Without error checking, something like ....

```
std::string input("14.3925125E");
std::string substring = input.substr(0, input.find('E'));
std::istringstream str(substring);
str >> double_value;
```

Comment: Instead of the stringstream, I would recommend using the C++11 `stod()` function, if available.